# Adobe Illustrator Vector colors appearance, hex code, RGB and CMYK completely different when opened on another computer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk, rgb

When I send my AI to my colleague, the colour appears to be different in her computer. And is not juz the appearance issue, the entire Hex code, RGB value and CMYK value were totally off. We both are using the same Adobe Illustrator CC.

Comment: Thats kindof the point of color management. But i betcha no one calibrated your monitors so you are getting meaningless color management.

Comment: No two devices will show the same colours, at least not without calibration. Colour calibration is a complex topic - probably best handled with a colour calibration device.

Answer (score 1):

Are you both using the exact same monitor model with the exact same settings? The same video card, drivers and operating system?

Assuming you don't, that's likely the main reason for this.

Comment: As our computer are provided by our company, the model of all accessories are exactly the sam

Answer (score 0):

**Most Likely** The hardware (monitors / laptops) are the main culprit. Always use the same screens to have an exact color reproduction.
If the HEX or RGB are off. Try to use in on a plain page and print them out separately once from your device and once from the other. and see if there is a difference in color. 
MAKE SURE BOTH DEVICES HAVE THE SAME PRINTER PROFILES AND OUTPUT MODES.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the numbers generating the colors have changed, not just the appearance of the colors.

Did your colleague change the color space of the document: from CMYK to RGB or vise versa?